# Update only specific objects

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

The problem in my code is when I make any updates for my objects especially the Geometry Model. My code will update every object in this Model with the same values. While I am tying is to update each row with its values instead of updating the model with the same values.

I have tried several ways but the problem still occurs.

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    geo = address_data.get('geo')

    lat = geo.pop('lat')
    lng = geo.pop('lng')
    ...
    gathers = geometry.objects.update(lat=lat, lng=lng)
    address = Address.objects.update(address=address, country=country, description=description, geo=gathers )

    ...

    user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
    username = user_data.pop('username')
    user = User.objects.update(username=username)

    gather = userProfile.objects.update(address=address, user=user)

    return instance.


class geometry(models.Model):
    lat = models.IntegerField(default='')
    lng = models.IntegerField(default='')

class Address(models.Model):
    ...
    geo = models.OneToOneField(geometry, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='')


class userProfile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, name='user', primary_key=True)
    address = models.OneToOneField(Address, on_delete=models.CASCADE, name='address')
```

The problem is my code updating the whole rows in the model with the same values.

```
{
    "address": {
        "id": 1,
        "address": "2,lot chragua",
        "country": "Morocco",
        "description": "dfvfdv",
        "geo": {
            "id": 1,
            "lat": 471,
            "lng": 39
        }
    },
    "user": {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "sdfvedfbf",
        "first_name": "",
        "last_name": "",
        "email": "",
        "date_joined": "2019-01-19T11:31:00.415990Z",
        "last_login": null
    }
},
{
    "address": {
        "id": 2,
        "address": "2.Lot Chraga",
        "country": "Morocco",
        "description": "sfvsfv",
        "geo": {
            "id": 2,
            "lat": 471,
            "lng": 39
        }
    },
    "user": {
        "id": 2,
        "username": "svscwdc",
        "first_name": "",
        "last_name": "",
        "email": "",
        "date_joined": "2019-01-19T11:36:50.266225Z",
        "last_login": null
    }
}
```

Comment: To update a specific row data you need to filter the data then update it. For example `User.objects.filter(username='someone').update(first_name='Someones Firstname')` . Without filtering of course it will update all data.

Answer (score 0):

The `.update()` method is used to update multiple objects. As you found out, it will update all objects in a queryset.

If I understand you correctly you want to update a single instance, but from your code, it is not clear to me which instance that is.

You can filter the queryset, as @ozcanyarimdunya suggested:

```
geometry.objects.filter(pk=geo_pk).update(...)
```

It should be noted that `.update()` doesn't call `.save()` on your model or emit any signals. To update a single object, it is usually preferable to assign the new values to the instance and call save, like this:

```
geo = geometry.objects.get(pk=geo_pk)
geo.lat = lat
geo.lon = lon
geo.save()
```

On a side note, the common convention is to capitalize class names (`Geometry` instead of `geometry`).